# When would ArrayList-add/Array-get List Builder be faster than ArrayList?

Tags: java, arrays, optimization, arraylist

I trying to implement a Builder-pattern that is comparable to LinkedList when adding and comparable to ArrayList when getting.

When the function f() is chosen to be "(int)(Math.random() * ((len) + 1))" and N is chosen to be 100000, my implementation is only just about as fast as ArrayList (and both are about 1000 times faster than LinkedList).

So, could anyone give me any pointers towards solving this? Either by rethinking my implementation, or by finding a function f() that fulfils the requirements?

Comment: Using arrayList internally, you are trying to make your customized list faster than ArrayList itself?

Comment: Yeah, I'm using arrayList in add, but then I convert it to an Array before I get. So the get should still be faster right?

Comment: That sounded strange to me too, @almas!

Comment: You may convert to Array as much as you want, but if you use ArrayList it will take the time of ArrayList for perfoming the tasks, plus the time of you algorithm. This is nonsense!

Comment: @aerugo you are adding overhead by converting to array. If you look inside arrayList, arraylist itself uses array.

Comment: If you want to be better than ArrayList, you are going to have to develop your own structure and work hard. JVM structures are well optimized, my friend.

Comment: @ederpsampaio Yeah, that makes sense. Still new to this, and I see now that I really shouldn't be expecting anything else from this.

Comment: The get operation is in both cases (ArrayList and Array) O(1).

Comment: Comparable, in time complexity or memory management? You can't have both.

Comment: You should expect exactly what you create, my friend. It's not impossible, but you'll have to work hard.

Comment: @Rudi aerugo is talking about fast, faster... So I assumed that he is talking about time complexity.

Comment: @Rudi, yeah, time complexity is correct (I think). Only instruction is that it should run _faster_.

Comment: If you're using `ArrayList` internally you have already failed your first criterion. Your specification amounts to *O(1)* for both insertion and access. There is no such data structure. It is impossible.

Answer (score 3):

When you convert your ArrayList to Array you use time,and that makes your implementation not optimal.
Also the implementation of ArrayList is based directly in Arrays and the method get is O(1).

If you want to do something faster than ArrayList you have to code your own class.